# How to assign an operator to a variable in golang?

Tags: go

Is it possible to assign an infix operator to a variable?

```
operator := <<
```

If so how is it applied to arguments?

Comment: just curious, what would be the use case?

Comment: Lol, a good question might be able to do it better. I'm writing a function for moving pawns in a chess application. Basically, if they are white I want to moves then using << and if they are black with >>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to store an operator in a variable.

Perhaps the best way is to define a set of operations and have a wrapper struct with an `Apply` method:

```
type Operation int

const (
  Left Operation = iota
  Right
)

type State struct {
  Value int
}

func (s *State) Apply(o Operation) {
  switch (o) {
    case Left:
       s.Value = s.value << 1
    case Right:
       s.Value = s.value >> 1
  }
}
```

Sample use:

```
value := State{4} // original value
op := Left
value.Apply(op) // s.Value is now 8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the operator in a function ([playground](https://play.golang.com/p/hEXmAhzSK_)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    operators := []func(int)int{left, left, left, right, right}

    value := 4

    for _, operator := range operators {
        value = operator(value)
        fmt.Println(value)
    }
}

func left(x int) int {
    return x << 1
}

func right(x int) int {
    return x >> 1
}
```

This prints:

> 8
>   16
>   32
>   16
>   8